# Understanding coherent sheaf obtained via sheaf injections of holomorphic vector bundles on $T\mathbb{C}P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

My problem involves holomorphic vector bundles $E,F$ of the same rank on $T\mathbb{C}P^1$. I have a short exact sequence of sheaves
$$0\rightarrow E\rightarrow F\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0.$$

I want to know what information I can glean about this torsion, coherent sheaf $Q$. In my case, I know *a prioi* that $Q$ is supported on a compact curve $D$, which is an effective divisor. However, I do not know if the curve is smooth. I've tried looking in Friedman's "Algebraic surfaces and holomorphic vector bundles", especially at elementary modifications, but I do not know if $Q$ is a vector bundle on $D$.

I believe that if the curve were smooth, then I could say that $Q\mid D$ is torsion-free away from a finite number of points (as $D$ is compact). But I'm not sure about what would happen if $D$ were not smooth.

Comment: Is there any more information about your situation you can share? E.g. why do you know that $Q$ is supported on an effective divisor?

Comment: My problem deals with monopoles, solutions to the Bogomolny equation. $D$ is essentially defined by the place where $Q$ has support. Previous work by others has shown that $D$ is compact.

For more context, my problem has $F$ as the solutions to a differential equation. Then $E$ is the direct sum of subbundles of $F$, each with decay conditions. $D$ measures where these subbundles intersect nontrivially. Also, in my case, away from $D$, the subbundles span $F$. That is, I have the short exact sequence of sheaves $$0\rightarrow E^+\oplus E^-\rightarrow F\rightarrow F/(E^++E^-)\rightarrow 0.$$